# Generate random words in Python and store into csv

Tags: python

I used the following code to do so:

```
import csv
from random_words import RandomWords
rw = RandomWords()
TRACK_TERMS = rw.random_words(count = 400)
with open('RandomWords.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(TRACK_TERMS)
```

there are two problems:
the first is that my result on each row is like: each character takes a cell, so cat would be c  a  t   taking 3 columns. If I change the last row of my code to `writer.writerow(TRACK_TERMS)`  each word will take a cell, but the results are in different columns rather than different rows.

Another problem is that even though I specified count = 400, I have 700 words in my csv, I don't know why. 
TRACK_TERM should be a list of strings, and I want the length of the list to be 400

Comment: What is `random_words`?

Comment: it is a tool used to generate random_words, if you have better solution to do this please tell me too.

Comment: What exactly is the output of `rw.random_words(count = 400)`?  The shape of that will effect what `writerows` does according to the [default dialect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params)

Comment: the output is a list of strings

Comment: [`writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) takes a `list` of iterables that themselves contain strings.  Try something like `TRACK_TERMS = [(s,) for s in rw.random_words(count = 400)]`

Comment: Thanks, it now looks like what I want, but there is an empty row between each two rows, how to remove that? And what does (s,) mean?

Comment: `(s,)` is a tuple with a single thing inside it.  The default newline character is `\r\n`, which some things may read as two newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
import csv

from random_words import RandomWords

rw = RandomWords()
TRACK_TERMS = rw.random_words(count=400)
with open('RandomWords.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter="\n")
    writer.writerow(TRACK_TERMS)
```

You have to use delimiter. You can find more information [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: This gives exactly what I want.